# Is there a way to use the Virtualbox Android as an emulator from VS

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin

Since the emulator coming with the SDK is really slow, I wanted to try to connect to an emulator which is running in Virtualbox. 
But when I have to select the device I get the IP:port, but it's disabled. I suppose it's considered as a real device. Is there a way to use it somehow as an emulator? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

There is more information about [faster emulator](http://www.bobbychanblog.com/2011/07/faster-android-emulator-alternative-using-virtualbox/)

> I get the IP:port, but it's disabled

Before you must set Network Adapters

in VirtualBox "(Your virtual machine name)"->**Settings->Network Adapters->Adapter1->Attached to**

You must choose  **Only-host Adapter**

after typed #**netcfg** you show eth0 's ip

Comment: the link you've provided solves the problem for Eclipse, I'm trying to achieve the same thing in Visual Studio. The device appears in the list, but it's not selectable

Comment: I've changed to Host-only adapter, but I get the same behavior in the device list

Answer (score -1):

Check out the new Android Emulator for Visual studio

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx